# Cronjob to load OSM data into PostgreSQL with ogr2ogr fails

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr2ogr

I try to load daily updates from OSM into a PostgreSQL database. For this I download daily dumps from Geofabrik and load them into my database using ogr2ogr.

My script runs fine when running from command line, however, when I run it as a cronjob (as the same user as I used for the command line), some of the larger files don't get uploaded.

I wrote the output from ogr2ogr into a logfile and got this:

```
INFO:root:Download http://download.geofabrik.de/africa/equatorial-guinea-latest.osm.pbf
INFO:root:Load file into PostgreSQL
INFO:root:''
INFO:root:Download http://download.geofabrik.de/africa/cameroon-latest.osm.pbf
INFO:root:Load file into PostgreSQL
INFO:root:'ERROR 1: Cannot copy /vsimem/osm_importer/osm_temp_nodes_0x7581a0 to ./osm_tmp_nodes3242959232_0\n'
DEBUG:root:Load file into PostgreSQL
INFO:root:'ERROR 1: Cannot copy /vsimem/osm_importer/osm_temp_nodes_0x115c1a0 to ./osm_tmp_nodes396976512_0\n'
INFO:root:Refresh materialized view CMR
INFO:root:Download http://download.geofabrik.de/africa/congo-democratic-republic-latest.osm.pbf
INFO:root:Load file into PostgreSQL
INFO:root:'ERROR 1: Cannot copy /vsimem/osm_importer/osm_temp_nodes_0x79c130 to ./osm_tmp_nodes4052980096_0\n'
DEBUG:root:Load file into PostgreSQL
INFO:root:'ERROR 1: Cannot copy /vsimem/osm_importer/osm_temp_nodes_0xbee130 to ./osm_tmp_nodes2294854016_0\n'
INFO:root:Refresh materialized view COD
INFO:root:Download http://download.geofabrik.de/africa/congo-brazzaville-latest.osm.pbf
INFO:root:Load file into PostgreSQL
INFO:root:''
```

As mentioned before, I don't get this error when running the script directly. I use the same settings for all files I download. Some of them work, other not.

Does anyone have a hint why my cronjob is failing?

Comment: Only big files produce error ?

Comment: Yes, you can see that two files pro

Comment: Yes, two smaller files get processed correctly

Comment: You run the script on server or from your local ?

Comment: On the server. When I run it from the command line it works. When with running the same script on the same server with the same user as cronjob it fails

Comment: When you run the script manually from the server, you managed to download the big size files ?

Comment: Yes, all works fine